# Can't sendkeys to KindEditor

Tags: c#, selenium

I am using Selenium WebDriver in C# and I am trying to insert text into a KindEditor box on a web page. This is the code I am using.

```
        var textarea = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("ke-edit-iframe"));
        driver.SwitchTo().Frame(textarea);
        driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body")).SendKeys("ldlflflflf");
        driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
```

The cursor is blinking inside of the editor, however no text is sent. I have also tried this slight variation without any luck.

The editor demo : http://kindeditor.org/demo

Comment: Your code seems legit. I've tried the same methods with Java and it's working. What is your selenium version, which browser and browser version are you trying?

Comment: I've succeed ^^ thx